# SQL NULL Products

Tags: sql, not-exists

I have to make it to show how many categories are available that are not currently any products in. Not sure what I am doing wrong, since I have moved stuff around and still get the result of 682 rows when there is supposed to be 0.

```
SELECT 
    Quantity, 
    ProductName, 
    CategoryID

FROM 
    Products,
    OrderItems 

WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Quantity
    FROM OrderItems
    WHERE Quantity IS NULL
)
```

Was told that "NOT EXIST" needs to be used in it.

Comment: You need to join the two tables you are selecting from... otherwise the results will not be what you are expecting.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You need a join condition between the tables.  First hint:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

I assume you want something like this:

```
SELECT oi.Quantity, p.ProductName, p.CategoryID
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     OrderItems oi
     ON oi.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE oi.quantity IS NULL;
```

The exact syntax is a bit of a guess, because you don't provide sample data.

Comment: I don't agree with the "never use commas" statement. Rather, I think that if one knows what one is doing, then it is ok to use commas...

Comment: @Gordon yes like that but was told that NOT EXIST has to be used

Comment: @PeterAbolins . . . The type of join should *always* be explicitly declared.  If not, then the person writing the query (1) probably doesn't know what they are doing and (2) doesn't care if anyone else can understand what they intend.